# How to properly scale an imageview within parent layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

In my App. I have a RelativeLayout containing an ImageView.
The RelativeLayout is set to MATCH_PARENT horizontally and WRAP_CONTENT vertically.

The ImageView is set to WRAP_CONTENT both horizontally and vertically. The image Drawable is a 24x24 Vector icon.

Because the icon is too small to be seen, I want to double its size. That's where the issue is:

```
// Parent RelativeLayout
    RelativeLayout titleLayout = new RelativeLayout(MyApplication.getContext());
    titleLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
//Icon
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams information_icon_layout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    information_icon_layout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

    ImageView information_icon = new ImageView(MyApplication.getContext());
    information_icon.setLayoutParams(information_icon_layout);
    information_icon.setPadding(
            getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.schedule_element_title_layout_padding_left),
            getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.schedule_element_title_layout_padding_top),
            getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.schedule_element_title_layout_padding_right),
            getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.schedule_element_title_layout_padding_bottom)
    );
    information_icon.setImageDrawable(MyApplication.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_info_outline_black_24dp));
    information_icon.setScaleX(2);
    information_icon.setScaleY(2);
    information_icon.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

The icon scales as expected, but the parent RelativeLayout does not seem to take into account this change, and still calculates its vertical size using the original size of the Icon (24x24).
As a result, the icon is scaling outside of the parent, and only part of it is visible.

My question: How can I tell the parent RelativeLayout to take into account the scaled size of the icon?

Answer (score 0):

Use scaletype property of an imageview it has main 3 property
center,
centercrop,
centerinside,
And if you want to scratch the image fully it also has property as fit center,fit end,fit start,fitxy.You can use this property in xml as well as java.
here is the link

[scaletyper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType)

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your reply. I added setScaleType to my ImageView, tried every single Scaletype (from CENTER to MATRIX), but the parent RelativeLayout still doesn't take into account the new image size, and cuts the sides of my ImageView.

Comment: @Eric did u use fitxy ??

Comment: Yep. No mater which Scaletype I use, the RelativeLayout vertical size does not change.

Comment: use a fixed size for the height and width for image view like 100 dp  or 80 dp.

Comment: Seems better, I should be able to make it work using fixed size. Thank you!